# Elastic Search Load Testing With Apache Benchmark

Tags: elasticsearch, apachebench

I am using the elastic cloud to store my data. My index has 1.3 million documents and I am using apache benchmark to perform load testing on my elastic search index. I am using the following command to perform load testing:

```
ab -p <<file.txt>> -T application/json -c 500 -n 50000 -t 60 -l <<elastic url>>
```

After running above command I get the following result:

```
Complete requests:9000
Failed requests: 0
```

In the request, I have mentioned the number of requests is 50 000 and concurrency is 500 but the total completed request is 9 000 only. How I increase completed request count?
Is any setting in elastic search to support max request concurrency(like 500)?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Indian words here. That's just going to confuse people.

Comment: same here facing the same problem , if you find out please let me know.